# Retain pixels in an image that are not black

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I want to process an color image and retain only the pixels that are not black. I wrote some code but it does not appear to do what i think it is doing:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorly as tl

def eq_svtn(T, b, M, Omega):
X = 0
for i in range(3):
    X += b[i]*tl.fold(M[i],i,T.shape)
X = X/np.sum(b)

for i in range(T.shape[0]):
    for j in range(T.shape[1]):
        if Omega[i, j, :].all() != 0:
            X[i, j, :] = T[i, j, :]
return X

def silrtc(X,b,K,O):
a = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1)
a = a[0,:]
M = [0, 0, 0]
for i in range(K):
    X1 = tl.unfold(X, 0)
    X2 = tl.unfold(X, 1)
    X3 = tl.unfold(X, 2)
    u1, s1, v1 = LA.svd(X1, full_matrices=False)
    u2, s2, v2 = LA.svd(X2, full_matrices=False)
    u3, s3, v3 = LA.svd(X3, full_matrices=False)
    U = [u1,u2,u3]
    V = [v1,v2,v3]
    S = [s1,s2,s3]
    for j in range (3):
        M[j] = shrinkage_op(U[j],V[j],S[j],a[j]/b[j],X.shape)
    X = eq_svtn(X,b,M,O)
return X


im = cv2.imread('target.jpg')
original_shape = im.shape
zzo = np.zeros(im.shape)
shp = (int(original_shape[0]),int(mt.floor(0.9*original_shape[1])),int(original_shape[2]))
shp2 = (int(original_shape[0]),int(mt.ceil(0.1*original_shape[1])),int(original_shape[2]))
zz = np.zeros(shp)
oo = 0xFF*np.ones(shp2)
cct = np.concatenate((zz,oo),1)
np.random.shuffle(cct.reshape(-1, 3))
cct = cct.astype(np.uint8)
im2 = np.bitwise_and(im,cct)
b = [0.0001, 0.0001,0.0001]
xx = silrtc(im2,b,64,cct)
```

A black pixel is [0,0,0], `b` is an array of 3 floats, `M` is a set of 2-D arrays (matrices), `T` is the image (3-D array, a tensor) with black pixels in it, `X` is a color image with black pixels removed.

Comment: I don't think `T[i, j, :].all() != 0` does what you want. But even if it did, what are you trying to accomplish? You initialize `X` to 0, then copy the non-zero pixels over. At the end, `X` should be identical to `T`, no?

Comment: `X` should only be equal to `T` for pixels that are not black. The problem is that `T` is generated from `im` but it does not retain true black pixels ([0,0,0]) after it is generated so checking for 0 does not work. I would have to pass the positions of the pixels i do not want to retain into this function in order for it to work as i would like.

Comment: I don't see where `T` is generated at all, so can't test your claim there. But the question is: what do you want to do with the zero pixels? Also: is your indenting wrong in the code? Can't understand what it does!

Comment: `T[i, j, :].all()` returns true only if none of the values are 0. You want to test if all values are zero. Those are different things. Try using `any` instead.

Comment: I added more of the code. Should be more clear now.
I want to retain pixels that are not black, so I want `X` to take those pixels from `T` that are not black.

Comment: But did you try `any`? `if not Omega[i, j, :].any():` should trigger copying the pixel only if `Omega[i,j,:]` is not `[0,0,0]`.

Comment: I did try it, i got a fully black image.

Comment: i did it this way: `if all(Omega[i, j, :]!= 0):` seems to work well.